# How to return column index for every row where a certain value appears for the first time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas, where 1 appears in different columns for every rows. The column where 1 appears for the first time in a row is different for different rows. I need to create an additional column (column index) in which as value I want to return the index number of the column where 1 appears for the first time in that row.

```
Example dataframe:

IDs     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8

1111    0     0     0      1    0      0     0     1

1122    0     0     1      0    0      1     0     0

the output should like this: 

IDs     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8    column_index

1111    0     0     0      1    0      0     0     1        5

1122    0     0     1      0    0      1     0     0        4
```

It would be helpful if anyone can provide the code useful in pandas. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.argmax(df.eq(1).values, axis=1) + 1`, although you might want to account for it appearing in your `IDs`  column (unless that is the index).  `pandas` has `idxmax`, but that will return the column header, not the integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just write a simple function and then use apply on the dataframe.

```py
def get_first(row):
    for i, col in enumerate(row.index.tolist()):
        if row[col] == 1:
            return i

df['column_index'] = df.apply(get_first, axis=1)
```

Probably a cool tricky way to do this with pandas, but this works.

You could also do this if you don't want to write a function, but it's a lot less readable

```py
df['first_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row.index.tolist().index(c) for c in row.index.tolist() if row[c] == 1][0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `idxmax` and `get_indexer` from `df.columns`

```
df['column_index'] = df.columns.get_indexer(df.drop('IDs',1).idxmax(1))+1

Out[52]:
    IDs  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  column_index
0  1111   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1             5
1  1122   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0             4
```

Answer (score 1):

try something very basilar such as follows:

```
for i in range(df.iloc[:,0].size):

    j=0
    while df.iloc[i,j]=!1:
        df.iloc[i,'index column']=j
        j=j+1
```

regards